# How to configure two jack rabbit servers in clustering?

Tags: apache, tomcat, jcr, jackrabbit, cmis

I need suggestions on the clustering of jack rabbit like this, can anyone provide the references.

There is server 1&2 and jackrabbit server 1 & 2 are there. Every jack rabbit server created one jack rabbit folder.

If server1 access jack rabbit server 2, required content are not available. 
How can I achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The scenario of having 2 servers is pretty common. It's all a matter of configuring Apache Jackrabbit to set this up. For clarity I assume you're using Apache Jackrabbit 2.x and not OAK.

With Jackrabbit 2 you can configure clustering between 2 servers in two ways:

**Using a network share**

You can use a shared network drive. In your Jackrabbit repository configuration (repository.xml) you will need to configure the cluster element based on a FileJournal.

```
<Cluster id="node1">
  <Journal class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.journal.FileJournal">
    <param name="revision" value="${rep.home}/revision.log" />
    <param name="directory" value="/nfs/myserver/myjournal" />
  </Journal>
</Cluster>
```

**Using a database**

You can use a database to share the content and the journal (required for synching the different repositories. In the below example we'll use Oracle, but it could be any kind of RDBMS.

```
<Cluster id="node1" syncDelay="2000">
  <Journal class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.journal.OracleDatabaseJournal">
    <param name="revision" value="${rep.home}/revision.log" />
    <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:mydb" />
    <param name="user" value="scott"/>
    <param name="password" value="tiger"/>
  </Journal>
</Cluster>
```

In both cases it's very important to set a different ID on the Cluster element, so that Jackrabbit knows which nodes still needs to be updated.

See the Apache [Jackrabbit Clustering](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Clustering) page for more information.

Comment: That's great! Can you mark the question as answered?